# Drag and Drop and single click style. Why did it work TWICE?

Tags: .net, drag-and-drop

my application uses Drag & Drop operations. Everything worked perfect. Recently, some user changed system options:

Control Panel --> Folder Options --> Single click to open an item (point to select).

And now all my drag & drop operations worked **TWICE**. How could it be ? What should I change to avoid that type of behaviour ?

Comment: You should change your code.  Probably.

Comment: No, Code is the same but behaviour is different.

Answer (score 0):

Check this thread: [C# ListView DragDrop Event Method Executing Twice Per Drop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075765/c-sharp-listview-dragdrop-event-method-executing-twice-per-drop)

This usually happens if you added the event handlers yourself, by hand, and then double-clicked (e.g.) the event in the designer assuming all that does is create an empty method to put your code in. It does but it also adds the very same event handlers in the XYZ.Designer.cs file.